# Django Models UnManaged to Managed

Tags: python, django-models

Does changing Django Model from `managed=False` to `managed=True` affect the data ?

I have a large table of a Model that has `managed=False` and want to add a new field to it. adding a field using migration can't be done without changing the model to `managed=True`

Is it safe to just change it to `managed=True` , migrate the change, then update fields ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. It is **safe** and **required**. I have read django documentation about your problem. That says that:

> `Managed` option defaults to True, meaning Django will create the
> appropriate database tables in migrate or as part of migrations and
> remove them as part of a flush management command. That is, Django
> manages the database tables’ lifecycles.
>
> If False, **no database table creation, modification, or deletion
> operations will be performed for this model.**

If your django model option `managed=False` then make it `managed=True`, otherwise your migration of models won't work. For more info read [django documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/)